# How to get particular keys from an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object:

```
a = {
"1": "abc",
"2": "def",
"3": "ghi",
"4": "jkl"
}
```

and an array:
`b = ['abc','ghi']`
I want to get keys from the objects which values are in an array and place them in another array, so expected output is: `['1', '3']`.

I have no idea how to filter object properties.
I tried mapping an array and get values but I get undefined.

```
    const result = b.map(v => a[v])
```

Comment: `Object.entries()` + `.filter()`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.keys(a).filter(...)`, and only return true if `a[key]` is in the `b` array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const a = {"1": "abc", "2": "def", "3": "ghi", "4": "jkl"}; 
const b = ['abc','ghi']

const c = Object.keys(a).filter(k => b.includes(a[k]));
console.log(c);
```